# datepicker beforeshowday return not working

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm trying to use `beforeShowDay` to disable and highlight days from the calendar. I found this Fiddle code that works. When I return `false` it works and disables that day, but I am trying to return `[false, 'holiday', '']` with a CSS class, but it's not working or not disabling dates.

```js
        function add_zero(num){
        if(num<10){
            return '0'+num;
        }else{
            return num;
        }
    }
$('.date').datepicker({
  format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
  weekStart: [1],
  beforeShowDay: function(Date) {
    var array = <?php echo json_encode($arry); ?>;
    var curr_day = add_zero(Date.getDate());
    var curr_month = add_zero(Date.getMonth() + 1);
    var curr_year = Date.getFullYear();
    var curr_date = curr_month + '-' + curr_day + '-' + curr_year;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (curr_date == array[i]) {
        // return false;
        return [false, 'holiday', ''];
      }
    }
    //return [true,''];
    return true;
  }
}).on('changeDate', cal_date);
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? What is the output from `var array = <?php echo json_encode($arry); ?>;`?

Comment: console.log(curr_date+' '+array[i]); in for loop , out put is 05-01-2019 05-01-2019

Comment: describe add_zero function here

Comment: function add_zero(num){
            if(num<10){
                return '0'+num;
            }else{
                return num;
            }
        }         use for add 0 to single number, same like array[i] return date, ex:5-5-2019 convert to 05-05-2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly issue seems in your php date formats.

[jsfiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/1dgaujbn/1/)

```
var highlight = ['2019/05/19', '2019/05/20'];
//tips are optional but good to have
var tips = ['some description', 'some other description'];
var disable_dates = ['2019/05/01', '2019/05/08', '2019/05/15', '2019/05/22', '2019/05/29']
$('.date').datepicker({

  format: "mm-dd-yyyy",
  autoclose: true,
  daysOfWeekDisabled: [0],
  weekStart: [1],
  beforeShowDay: function (date) {
        var datestring = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy/mm/dd', date);
        var hindex = $.inArray(datestring, highlight);
        if (hindex > -1) {
            return [true, 'highlight yourcustomcss', tips[hindex]];
        }
        var aindex = $.inArray(datestring, disable_dates);
                if(aindex == -1)
                    return [true,'custom_enabled']
                else
          return [false,'custom_disabled']
    }
})
```

Comment: its cannt be posibale. when place consol.log(curr.date+' '+array[i]) code in if contion, all of holidays are printed,because if condition is true,